# What's the better way to get highest couple of values from an array of keys in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

What's the better way to get the  highest value from an array of hashes? I want to get highest ID value from each file, content in my array (keys are file name and ID).

my `@array` contains these values

```perl
[
    { file => "messages0.0", id => "1", },
    { file => "messages0.1", id => "2", },
    { file => "messages0.3", id => "3", },
    { file => "messages1.0", id => "1", },
    { file => "messages1.1", id => "2", },
    { file => "messages2.0", id => "1", },
    { file => "messages2.1", id => "1", }
]
```

If I use

```perl
my @new_array = sort { $b->{id} <=> $a->{id} } @array;
```

If I have value greater than 10 then `sort` function doesn't works correctly

```
messages0.0.log;1
messages1.0.log;1
messages2.0.log;1
messages2.1.log;1
messages1.0.log;10
messages1.0.log;11
```

Here is my array content (with field separated by `;` for a better view

```
messages1.0.log;12
messages1.0.log;11
messages1.0.log;10
messages1.0.log;9
messages0.0.log;8
messages1.0.log;8
messages0.0.log;7
messages1.0.log;7
messages0.0.log;6
messages1.0.log;6
messages0.0.log;5
messages1.0.log;5
messages2.0.log;5
messages2.1.log;5
messages0.0.log;4
messages1.0.log;4
messages2.0.log;4
messages2.1.log;4
messages2.0.log;3
messages2.1.log;3
messages0.0.log;3
messages0.2.log;3
messages0.3.log;3
messages1.0.log;3
messages2.0.log;3
messages2.1.log;3
messages0.3.log;2
messages0.2.log;2
messages0.0.log;2
messages1.0.log;2
messages2.0.log;2
messages2.1.log;2
messages0.0.log;1
messages0.2.log;1
messages0.3.log;1
messages1.0.log;1
messages1.1.log;1
messages2.0.log;1
messages2.1.log;1
```

My desired output is

```
messages1.0.log;12
messages0.0.log;8
messages2.0.log;5
messages2.1.log;5
messages0.2.log;3
messages0.3.log;3
messages1.1.log;1
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $STAT = ".logstatistics";

open( STAT, '>', $STAT ) or die $!;

my @new_array = sort { $b->{id} <=> $a->{id} } @array;

# Print Log statistics
foreach my $entry ( @new_array ) {
    print STAT join ';', $entry->{file}, "$entry->{id}\n";
}

close( STAT );
```

To help me with the analysis I've written the following code to load the array from a file

```
open( STAT, $STAT );

while ( <STAT> ) {
    my @lines = split /\n/;
    my ( $file, $id ) = $lines[0] =~ /\A(.\w.*);(\d.*)/;
    push @array, { file => $file, id => $id, };
}

close( STAT );
```

I've solved my problem with an `if` statement into data loading into `@array`.
if the old value of the file name is the same as the current value it is skipped.
In this way, I have only one value for each file.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Equality-Operators . See the `<=>` operator

Comment: *"get highest value from an array"* or *"get couple of highest value from an array"* Which is it?

Comment: Please don't use `Data::Print`: it takes a lot of work to change it into something I can compile. @sobrique: see what you've done!

Comment: *"if i have value greater than 10 sort function doesn't works correctly"* Please post an example of data that *doesn't work*. We can hardly fix things that work!

Comment: How do `messages0.0.log;1` etc. relate to your original data? Please show the code that does this. We cannot work without proper information.

Comment: Is the output an example of what you want, or is it what your code produces?

Comment: Please give us some Perl code that defines your input array (and I mean compilable Perl code, not that almost-Perl mess that we currently have) along with the output that you require. Without that, we're just guessing. And that's just a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: sorry my computer went on vacation (blue screen of death).
I re-align myself and I reply to everyone, but I thank you immediately for the many answers <3

Comment: Can you show the actual Perl data structure (your "array"), and specify the sorting criteria (or show exact expected output)?  In other words, can you respond to the comments that people kindly posted (by editing the question appropriately)? It is not possible to help you with what is in the question now.  With a good question you'd have solid answers (a while ago by now) instead of many comments asking for fixes.

Comment: @clarkseth: Not really. You still haven't given us Perl code that defines your array, have you?

Comment: @clarkseth: And looking at your code, it seems you have an array of hashes. That's mentioned nowhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# This seems to be the data structure that you are working with
my @data = ( {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 12,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 11,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 10,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 9,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 8,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 8,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 7,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 7,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 6,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 6,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 5,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 5,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 5,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 5,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 4,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 4,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 4,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 4,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.2.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.3.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 3,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.3.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.2.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 2,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.0.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.2.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages0.3.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.0.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages1.1.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.0.log', id => 1,
}, {
  file => 'messages2.1.log', id => 1,
});

my %stats;

# Walk your input data, making a note of the highest
# id associated with every file.
for (@data) {
  if (($stats{$_->{file}} // 0) < $_->{id}) {
    $stats{$_->{file}} = $_->{id};
  }
}

# Walk the %stats hash in sorted order, printing
# the file and the maximum associated id.
for ( sort my_clever_sort keys %stats) {
  say join ';', $_, $stats{$_};
}

# (Slightly) clever sorting algorithm
sub my_clever_sort {
  # Extract the floating point numbers from the filenames
  my ($str_num_a) = $a =~ /(\d+\.\d+)/;
  my ($str_num_b) = $b =~ /(\d+\.\d+)/;

  # Sort by id (descending) and then filename (ascending)
  return ($stats{$b} <=> $stats{$a}) || ($str_num_a <=> $str_num_b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
my @new_array = sort { $a->{id} cmp $b->{id} } @array;
```

try this

```
my @new_array = sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id} } @array;
```

The `<=>` operator treats the fields to compare as numbers instead of strings. It will treat 10 as greater than 3, so it will treat `10` as greater than `03`.

The `cmp` operator treats your values as strings, so it will sort `21` before `3` just as it would sort `BA` before `C`.

Comment: Great. Leaving `messages0.3` etc. in a random order. Do you really think that's what is required? Please always test your code and post the output.

Comment: *"even if they're strings"* and *"even if they're numbers"*. Perl variables are *both* strings and numbers all of the time. The type of the variable's contents are prescribed by the *operator*.